# $\sigma_{A,B}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $A,B$ be two bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $E$. We define

\begin{multline*}
\sigma_{A,B}=\Bigl\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C}\,;\;\exists\,\{x_n\}\subseteq E\; \text{ such that }\;\|x_n\|=1
\text{ and }\;\lim_{n\to+\infty}\|(A+\lambda B)x_n\|=0\;  \Bigr\}.
\end{multline*}

> Why $\sigma_{A,B}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{C}$?

That that if we remplace $B$ by $I$ and $\lambda$ by $-\lambda$ we get the definition of the approximate sprectrum.

Comment: Have you tried to show sequential closedness?

Comment: I tried to use sequences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $B=0$ we get $\sigma_{A,0}=\emptyset $ or $\sigma_{A,0}=\mathbb{C}. $

Let $B\neq 0.$
Assume $\lambda_0\notin \sigma_{A,B}.$ Then there exists $\delta >0$ such that $$\|(A+\lambda_0 B)x\|\ge \delta,\quad \|x\|=1$$
Let $|\lambda-\lambda_0|<{\delta\over \|B\|}.$ Then for $\|x\|=1,$ by applying the triangle inequality, we get
$$\|(A+\lambda B)x\|\ge \|(A+\lambda_0B)x\|-|\lambda-\lambda_0|\|Bx\|\ge \delta -|\lambda-\lambda_0|\|B\|>0 $$
Therefore $\lambda\notin \sigma_{A,B}.$ Summarizing the complement of $\sigma_{A,B}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}.$

Comment: Dear Professor, Thanks for your answer. I understand your ideas. But I feel to understand this fact: ''Assume $\lambda_0\notin \sigma_{A,B}.$ Then there exists $\delta >0$ such that $$\|(A+\lambda_0 B)x\|\ge \delta,\quad \|x\|=1$$

Comment: why you use $x$ instead of $x_n$? I will be greatful if you add more details in your answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: An equivalent condition for $\lambda\sigma_{A,B}$ is that for every $n$ there is an element $x_n,$ $\|x_n\|=1$ and $\|(A+\lambda B)x_n\|\le {1\over n}.$ Thus the condition $\lambda\notin \sigma_{A,B}$ means that for some $n$ we have $\|(A+\lambda B)x\|>{1\over n}$ for every $x$ such that $\|x\|=1.$ Please do not call me Professor. Ryszard is fine.